# Asp.net core CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting() is null

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage

I have an asp.net 4 application where it works fine, but I can't get it working for asp.net core. The documentation says that `GetSetting` looks in either `web.config` or `app.config` file.
Storage emulator is turned on.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    AzureConfig.Initialize();
}

public static void Initialize()
{
    //Always null
    var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
}
```

root web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have these dependencies in my project.json:

```
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "3.2.1",
"WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.1.2",
"AzureSDK2.2DLLs": "1.0.0"
```

**Edit**, this doesn't work either:

```
  {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "..."
    "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET core, the settings have been moved out of the web.config and in to appsettings.json. Have a look at the documentation for how it has changed:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Also, have a look at this previous answer to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30580006/2823539

Comment: That second link was what I needed. Thanks.