# What is the full, direct .NET Core equivalent of CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(<setting>, false);?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I am somewhat new to Azure, but have been looking all over the Internet for a full answer to this question and haven't had one.

(There have been 1. [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057194/error-system-dllnotfoundexception-fusion-dll-on-azure-storage-using-visual-stud) 2. [near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551528/asp-net-core-cloudconfigurationmanager-getsetting-is-null) 3. [misses](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/596), but nothing that I can really fully apply.)

All I'm needing to do is to take this call from .NET Framework:

```
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("setting", false);
```

and translate it directly into .NET Core.

If I leave the above call within .NET Core code, it compiles just fine.  But then specifically at runtime, it complains about not being able to find `fusion.dll`.  .NET Core and .NET Standard projects act weird about things not either going through NuGet or being within the same project, and `fusion.dll` doesn't seem to apply very directly to NuGet.

How do you fix this, in layman's terms?  I'm new to Azure, so I can't get much of anything from context.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IConfiguration["settingName"]`

The `IConfiguration` instance can be found in `Startup.cs` (at least when the entry point is a basic HTTP API project in .NET Core), and it must be injected elsewhere.  This will read through multiple sources, including places like your `appSettings.json` file and your settings stored in Azure (although you will need to add code to connect it to things like Azure).

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4010)?

Seems you need to use the  **`GetEnvironmentVariable`**

```
 System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```