# Add property in azure table storage using Microsoft Bot Services

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-table-storage, azure-bot-service

I'm programming a chatbot, in the beginning, it's showing a menu and it is up to the user to choose the right information, what I try to do once the user chooses a piece of information the bot store it in a table using Azure Table Storage.

I use a c# as a programming language and SDK Bot Builder V4

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
   CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("bababa1");
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("UserChoice");
table.CreateIfNotExists();

MenuChoiceDao choiceUser = new MenuChoiceDao(
     ChooseInf, 
     turnContext.Activity.Id.ToString());
choiceUser.count = "1";

TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(choiceUser);
table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

And i add the following variable in web.config :

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="......" />
</appSettings>
```

When I execute the bot, it doesn't work and the value 'storageAccount' returns Null, also when I do the same code in a new project console App it works

Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Comment: Was looking for a concrete example for an answer but, at this time, I can offer the following examples and documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/README.md https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core, they have moved away from web.config and using JSON configuration files. Please see more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575689/how-do-we-use-cloudconfigurationmanager-with-asp-net-5-json-configs/30580006#30580006). Just a warning; you may come across these issues as well:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4010

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4047

Make sure using Microsoft.Azure.ConfigurationManager 4.0.0 not Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.3